# How to bind a raw_socket to an specific interface in kernelspace?

Tags: networking, network-programming, linux-kernel, bind, raw-sockets

My problem is, when I listen with PF_PACKET I also get the packets my box sends and which is undesirable.

```
err_create = sock_create(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL), sock);
```

Instead of ETH_P_ALL I tried ETH_P_IP, but then I only get packets send to my host. So my idea was to bind the socket to an interface. With 'sockaddr_ll' I can define the ifindex. But I found no function to get the index of my interface.. ioctl does not work in kernelspace.

..

```
memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
my_addr.sll_family = PF_PACKET;
my_addr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
// my_addr.sll_ifindex = 2; //I tried different numbers.. but then I got no packets 

err_bind = sock->ops->bind(sock, (struct sockaddr_ll *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to do, but you can look up a network device in the kernel via **dev_get_by_name()**.  But why are you trying to catch packets in the *kernel* in the first place?  That's what libpcap is for in *userspace*.